# Sys.WebForms.PageRequest error

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax

I currently have a page that is erroring out with the Generic code of 500.

I am looking for a steps I havent tried or for someone to point me in a direction for a possible solution that I haven't thought yet.

This error is generated when an ajax button is clicked.

**Steps I have taken**

- Check IIS logs, found nothing
- Check Event Viewer, found nothing
- Taken the    website out to the server in questions and run the website in debug mode, NO ERROR GENEREATED
- At IE    level dropped all security    precautions, hoping it was a    permissioning issue

**Environment running**

- Windows server 2008
- IE 8
- Ajax extensions 1.0

any help would be great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z(VS.71).aspx

Enabling application level tracing let me see the underlying error. Then debug from there.